# Ctrl+A, c doesn't create a new window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

It just won't work or create a new window. I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> in a screen session. Is that it? It just doesn't do anything. All other commands work...

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't do anything? Does ctrl-a questionmark list the commands? Without a config file both ctrl-a ctrl-c and ctrl-a c both create a new screen.

Answer (score 1):

According to the "man screen"

"C-a C-c (screen) Create a new window with a shell and switch to that window."

1. type screen - to start a new screen
2. Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and press <kbd>a</kbd>, then press <kbd>c</kbd>
3. A new screen will be started and attached.

Comment: 1. It's unclear whether you mean lowercase or uppercase letters and lowercase letters should be used in this case. 2. You could use `<kbd>` and `</kbd>` tags to denote keyboard keys in the same way they are used in the edited OP's post.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk When it comes to control sequences, the case is not important. Whether `Ctrl` is pressed for both `a` and `c` _is_ important.

Comment: @Kusalananda: OK, indeed, I stand corrected.